# Google Maps API Error: “"Position Error: Only secure origins are allowed"”

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, ionic3, secure-context

I have tried to integrate google map in ionic 3 android project. It works fine when run as 'ionic serve', but not in 'ionic cordova run android'. I see only a blank page on emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following document:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

> Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the user's location using the HTML5 Geolocation API from pages delivered by non-secure connections. This means that the page that's making the Geolocation API call must be served from a secure context such as HTTPS.

As I can see in the screenshot you are not using HTTPS.